# *nix mkfifo: Is it possible to modify metadata (i.e. last modified)

Tags: c, linux

Using `mkfifo` from C, is it possible to then set a last modified date (or other metadata that shows up in `ls`) on the produced file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create the pipe with `mkfifo` you can use `futimens` on the file descriptor to set the access/modification times, just like on a regular file.